# Reading multiple lines from a text file in a loop at bash

Tags: bash, loops, rows, cat

I am trying to write an archiver script in bash but there are too many files. They are realy too many.. about 1 million files.

I planned that, I will create the list of files with;

```
cd /path/to/log/directory/
find . -type f > logfilelist.txt
```

And then, I will tar and zip them with;

```
tar -cvf logarchive.tar $(cat logfilelist.txt) 
gzip logarchive.tar
```

But, because of returning too many lines from cat, the tar gives "Arg list too long" error.

So I tought that, if I can read the file in a loop, I can archive them piece by pece by using append mode of tar. But making a million-line loop is not logical. So, can I read the list file with multiple lines like this;

```
tar -cf logarchive.tar $(first 50000 lines of logfilelist.txt) 

for loop
do
tar -rvf logarchive.tar $(2nd,3rd,...,99th,100th 50000 lines of logfilelist.txt)  
done
```

is it possible to cat multiple lines from a file?

Comment: this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47407/cat-line-x-to-line-y-on-a-huge-file could help

Comment: `And then, I will tar and zip them with;` ? Why not just do just that from the start, like `cd /path/to/log/directory/ ; tar -cvf logarchive.tar .`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mapfile` which allows you to easily read lines and call a function after every N:

```
#!/bin/bash
archive() {
  tar -rvf logarchive.tar "${lines[@]}"
  lines=()
}
mapfile -t -c 50000 -C archive lines < logfilelist.txt
archive # Also call it for the last <50,000 lines
```

PS: This is an [XYProblem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in place of "How do I add a large number of files from a list to a tar archive?", and the answer to that is instead a much easier and better

```
tar -cf logarchive.tar --files-from logfilelist.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You use xargs.
This script add tar archive by row.

```
# append and create tar.
cat logfilelist.txt | xargs -n 1 -I {} tar -rvf logarchive.tar {}
# gzip tar achive.
gzip logarchive.tar
```